# Iperf with tcl expect command

Tags: tcl, expect

I want to run iperf command, by running a tclscript (automation). The iperf command to be run in another PC (Linux). I am using tclexpect to do the same and the requirement is to open a console and run the iperf command. Code is given below.

```
puts "\n Enter the port no : " 
gets stdin sprt

puts "\n Enter the display intervel (in sec) : "
gets stdin sint

global spawn_id
set timeout 40 

spawn telnet $ip
expect "login:"
send "$user\r"

set timeout 10

expect "Password:"
send "$password\r"

expect "$"
send "iperf -s -u -p $sprt -i $sint"
```

Please help me.

Comment: So what is the actual problem? Please describe how things are not working…

Comment: It cannot open a new terminal (console) on Linux PC and it cannot run iperf also. Moreover the control is not coming back to the main script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost done.

Change your last two lines like this.

```
expect ".*$"
send "pwd\r"
```